# Combining two conditions for configuring NFS Server

Tags: linux, nfs

Linux newbie here! Having a bit of trouble with writing the NFS config. I want to allow /directory/somedirectory to be accessed (read/write permission) to users that are part of 'group1' AND are also in the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

So the question is how to combine these two conditions?

```
/directory/somedirectory  *@group1 (rw)
/directory/somedirectory  192.168.0.0/24 (rw)
```

Would the above do the same thing? I am really new at this so my apologies if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFS [exports](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) doesn't deal in users, only hosts

> Each line contains an export point and a whitespace-separated list of clients allowed to mount the file system at that point

and further down in *Machine Name Formats*

> NIS netgroups may be given as @group. Only the host part of each netgroup members is consider in checking for membership. Empty host parts or those containing a single dash (-) are ignored.

Comment: Thanks @Iain for the response. Sorry if this may sound stupid but based on what I can understand I am able to specify hosts in export file just like I have done in the above example based on their IP addresses (i.e. /directory/somedirectory  192.168.0.0/24 (rw)). However I am not able to specify the group that can have certain permissions to the file in the export file, is that correct?